# Load constructor argument (values) on stack using ASM bytecode instrumentation

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I have been experimenting with ASM java library for instrumentation, however I couldn't find a way to load constructor argument values onto the stack while instrumenting the constructor and retrieve them using probes. I could add the method description ((Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V) to the stack however I need the values of these arguments

Answer (score 4):

You can load parameters with the `*LOAD` instructions, which you insert using the `visitVarInsn` method of `MethodVisitor`. For example, consider this constructor:

```
public Foo(int i, long l, int j) {}
```

The value you receive depends on the second parameter to the `visitVarInsn(int opcode, int index)` method:

- For constructors and instance methods, `0` is the receiver itself (`this`), and parameters are indexed from 1+
- For static methods, parameters are indexed from 0+
- `long` and `double` consume two local variable slots, so the index of the next parameter / local variable is `2 + previous index`

Applied to the example, this yields

- `ALOAD 0` loads `this` (or `super`)
- `ILOAD 1` loads the `i` parameter
- `LLOAD 2` loads the `l` parameter
- `ILOAD`**`4`** loads the `j` parameter

Comment: so you always put the object you're operating on in  the 1st parameter? Why is `this` used? Isn't 'this' the caller of the constructor?